# Uploading a folder to azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, dll, directory

I have a project that is in azure devops

Now I had to add a special DLL
which is inside a folder

And I tried to upload the project + the folder to AZURE

And the folder doesn't come up

I added it manually to the drum folder inside bin->debbug

I would appreciate it if you could help me

What I don't understand is how to upload a folder or a file that I paste inside the project

Comment: Please explain *why* you want to do this. Binaries should rarely be put into source control. Build outputs should **never** be put into source control. Also please let us know whether you are using Git or TFVC for version control.

Answer (score 1):

As of this time, however, it is not supported to upload folders or folder structure through Azure DevOps. You can only upload files.

Generally, we use git command to upload folders to Azure DevOps. If you are using Visual Studio or VS Code, you can also connect Azure DevOps repos to them and upload folders through them.